How can I scrape data efficiently and clean it?
I scraped data from a website and I am having trouble cleaning
this is the code, I scraped the data with. Is that best practice?
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

all_countries_links=[]
countries= []
all_data=[]
data_dict={}
data_value=[]
page1 = requests.get(f"https://data.un.org/")

def main(page):
    source = page.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
    all_page = soup.find("div",{"class","CountryList"}).find_all('a',href=True)
    for link in all_page:
        all_countries_links.append(link['href'])
        countries. append(link.text.strip())

def scrape_country(all_countries_links,countries):
     for country in all_countries_links[:2]:
        page2 = requests.get(f"https://data.un.org/{country}") 
        source = page2.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
        all_page= soup.find('ul',{'class','pure-menu-list'})
        tables = all_page.contents
        for table in tables:
            line = table.text.strip()
            all_data.append(line)
main(page1)
scrape_country(all_countries_links,countries)
file_path = "data.json"
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_data, f, indent=4) 
print(f"Data saved to {file_path}")

This is a small example of the data after collecting it.
[
    "",
    "General Information\n\nRegion\u00a0\n\u00a0\nSouthern Asia\nPopulation\u00a0(000, 2021)\n\u00a0\n39 835a\nPop. density\u00a0(per km2, 2021)\n\u00a0\n61a\nCapital city\u00a0\n\u00a0\nKabul\nCapital city pop.\u00a0(000, 2021)\n\u00a0\n4 114.0b\nUN membership date\u00a0\n\u00a0\n19-Nov-46\nSurface area\u00a0(km2)\n\u00a0\n652 864b\nSex ratio\u00a0(m per 100 f)\n\u00a0\n105.3a\nNational currency\u00a0\n\u00a0\nAfghani (AFN)\nExchange rate\u00a0(per US$)\n\u00a0\n77.1c",   
]

I tried to separate the data with this code:
cleaned_data =[]

# for line in cleaned_data:
#     print(line.split('\n'))
# new_data = [line for line in all_data.split()]

for line in all_data[:1]:
    for line2 in line.split():
        if line2 not in ["General","Information","Economic"," indicators","Social"," indicators"]:
            cleaned_data.append(line2)

But I was hoping to find a better way.

if you're using split() without arguments, it's sure you will never find " indicators". and putting it twice is useless. just delete the first space: "indicators"

your scrape_country function is dirty. you're converting the whole table into text with no control over what you're getting. of course you have problems cleaning it

For this type of task I'd recommend pandas .read_html() function:
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

country_url = "https://data.un.org/en/iso/af.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(country_url).content, "html.parser")

for table in soup.select("details table"):
    summary = table.find_previous("summary").text
    df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(table)))[0]
    df["table_name"] = summary
    print(df)
    print("-" * 80)

Prints:

...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                               Unnamed: 0         2010         2015          2021           table_name
0       GDP: Gross domestic product (million current US$)       14 699       18 713       17 877b  Economic indicators
1          GDP growth rate (annual %, const. 2015 prices)          5.2         -1.4            4b  Economic indicators
2                            GDP per capita (current US$)        503.6        543.8        469.9b  Economic indicators
3           Economy: Agriculture (% of Gross Value Added)         33.2         27.3       26.9d,b  Economic indicators
4              Economy: Industry (% of Gross Value Added)           13         10.8     12.8e,f,b  Economic indicators
5         Economy: Services and other activity (% of GVA)         53.8         61.9       60.4g,b  Economic indicators
6              Employment in agricultureh (% of employed)         54.7         47.1         42.4c  Economic indicators
7                 Employment in industryh (% of employed)         14.4           17         18.3c  Economic indicators
8                    Employment in servicesh (% employed)         30.9         35.8         39.4c  Economic indicators
9                       Unemploymenth (% of labour force)         11.5         11.4         11.2c  Economic indicators
10  Labour force participation rateh (female/male pop. %)  14.9 / 78.4  18.8 / 76.2  21.8 / 74.6c  Economic indicators
11                   CPI: Consumer Price Index (2010=100)          100          133          150b  Economic indicators
12          Agricultural production index (2014-2016=100)           93           96          111b  Economic indicators
13     International trade: exports (million current US$)          388          571      1 022h,c  Economic indicators
14     International trade: imports (million current US$)        5 154        7 723      9 683h,c  Economic indicators
15     International trade: balance (million current US$)      - 4 766      - 7 151    - 8 661h,c  Economic indicators
16     Balance of payments, current account (million US$)         -578      - 4 193      - 3 137c  Economic indicators
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                          Unnamed: 0          2010          2015           2021         table_name
0                         Population growth ratei (average annual %)           2.6           3.3           2.5c  Social indicators
1                           Urban population (% of total population)          23.7          24.8          25.8b  Social indicators
2                   Urban population growth ratei (average annual %)           3.7             4            ...  Social indicators
3                     Fertility rate, totali (live births per woman)           6.5           5.4           4.6c  Social indicators
4                   Life expectancy at birthi (females/males, years)   61.0 / 58.3   63.8 / 60.9   65.8 / 62.8c  Social indicators
5                Population age distribution (0-14/60+ years old, %)    48.2 / 3.9    44.9 / 4.0    41.2 / 4.3a  Social indicators
6                 International migrant stockj (000/% of total pop.)   102.3 / 0.4   339.4 / 1.0   144.1 / 0.4c  Social indicators
7                      Refugees and others of concern to UNHCR (000)      1 200.0k       1 421.4       2 802.9c  Social indicators
8                     Infant mortality ratei (per 1 000 live births)          72.2          60.1          51.7c  Social indicators
9                             Health: Current expenditure (% of GDP)           8.6          10.1           9.4l  Social indicators
10                               Health: Physicians (per 1 000 pop.)           0.2           0.3           0.3m  Social indicators
11                      Education: Government expenditure (% of GDP)           3.5           3.3         4.1h,n  Social indicators
12          Education: Primary gross enrol. ratio (f/m per 100 pop.)  80.6 / 118.6  83.5 / 122.7  82.9 / 124.2l  Social indicators
13        Education: Secondary gross enrol. ratio (f/m per 100 pop.)   33.3 / 66.9   36.8 / 65.9   40.0 / 70.1l  Social indicators
14  Education: Upper secondary gross enrol. ratio (f/m per 100 pop.)   17.8 / 42.7   27.1 / 52.6   28.5 / 52.4l  Social indicators
15                      Intentional homicide rate (per 100 000 pop.)           3.4           9.8           6.7l  Social indicators
16                   Seats held by women in national parliaments (%)          27.3          27.7            27o  Social indicators
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...

